# TypeError: Data location must be "memory" or "calldata" for parameter in function, but none was given

Tags: solidity

I am trying the following code but got that error.

If I add memory inside functions params I got new error:

TypeError: Data location can only be specified for array, struct or mapping types, but "memory" was given.

```
pragma solidity 0.8.7;

 mapping (string => uint) wallet;

function saveWalletData(uint _qty , string _name) public{
    wallet[_name] = _qty;
}

function consultarWallet(string _name) public view returns(uint){
    return wallet[_name];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`string` is a reference type in Solidity. For all reference types, you need to specify their data location ([docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.10/types.html#data-location)).

In this case, you can use `calldata` for both, because you're not modifying value of the `_name` variable.

```
function saveWalletData(uint _qty , string calldata _name) public{
    wallet[_name] = _qty;
}

function consultarWallet(string calldata _name) public view returns(uint){
    return wallet[_name];
}
```

If you wanted to modify the value in memory, you'd need to use `memory`.